# How to create/build/construct completely trackerless p2p(peer-to-peer)?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, utorrent, libtorrent

How can I create/build/construct completely trackerless p2p(peer-to-peer) distributed network architecture?

If i have seeds/peers with **static ip address** and seeds/peers in different **WANs**.

I read about [BTS](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) and [DHT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table)

also i found:

> **Torrent File Extensions**
>
> A trackerless torrent dictionary does not have an "announce" key. Instead, a trackerless torrent has a "nodes" key. This key should be set to the K closest nodes in the torrent generating client's routing table. Alternatively, the key could be set to a known good node such as one operated by the person generating the torrent. Please do not automatically add "router.bittorrent.com" to torrent files or automatically add this node to clients routing tables.

`nodes = [["<host>", <port>], ["<host>", <port>], ...]`

`nodes = [["127.0.0.1", 6881], ["your.router.node", 4804]]`

But, I didn't understand where should I flash(hard code) these ip addresses

Comment: I think you should transfer this question to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you ask is not really specific enough to be answered.

If your question is more "how do I instruct some specific client applications to join a common, "trackerless" swarm using known nodes?".

... then you should provide more information about which client application you have in mind - and that will ultimately depend on this client application ability to let you specify that.

If your question is more: "how do I write my own client application that will bootstrap on known nodes?"

... then, assuming you plan on using rasterbar libtorrent for that (which you tagged, and is the only one I've used), you can certainly do it by calling the DHT related methods: see http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html#start-dht-stop-dht-set-dht-settings-dht-state-is-dht-running

And that would be set inside your C++ or Python code, depending on how you embark libtorrent.

Hope that helps.